# Complement option in tr

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I can't understand the `complement` (-c) option in `tr` command used along with the replace mode (that is without any other options), for e.g:

> echo "a" | tr -c a b

Why does it produce:

> **ab**root@Slack

(`ab` string with no newline)?

Comment: You used `a` and `b` as `tr` arguments, but got `e` in the output?

Comment: This answer should help you: http://superuser.com/questions/1155362/complement-option-in-tr

Comment: @adc ?? That is a link to **this question**.

Comment: I got `ab` as output for your code on my machine, as it should be: It replaces everything except `a` with `b`, and that includes the newline from *echo*. I've no idea why you got `e` instead.

Comment: @techraf Sorry I've made a typo - the output is indeed ab. Thx for Your attention.

Comment: @DavidPostill: I apologize for the mistake... a cut'n'paste error. This is the correct link: http://superuser.com/questions/355581/how-do-the-s-t-and-c-options-of-the-tr-command-work-in-unix

Answer (score 7):

`tr` command processes all characters, including the non-printing ones.

`echo` in your example produces an output consisting of two characters:

- `a`
- newline character (`\n`)

In your call you ordered `tr` to replace all characters which complement `a` (in simple words: other than `a`) with `b`, so:

- it left the `a` character intact
- replaced the newline character with `b`.

---

Consider testing it with `printf` (which does not implicitly add a newline to the end, like `echo` does)

This produces the same input for `tr` as `echo`, so the output is also the same:

```
printf "a\n" | tr -c a b
ab[~]#
```

Compare with:

```
printf "a" | tr -c a b
a[~]#
```

And:

```
printf "a\n\n" | tr -c a b
abb[~]#
```